# Recursively implementation of squares/2

Tags: prolog

I started my studies of the logical paradigm recently and am struggling with the following problem.

How to RECURSIVELY implement the `squares/2` predicate that takes a variable `X` and a list of positive integers `Y` and up to `X` a list with the squares of the `Y` elements?

`?- squares(X, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]).`
`X = [1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36] .`

My attepmt:

```
squares([], []).
squares([H|T], [X|Squared_list]):-
    X is H*H,
    squares(T, Squared_list).
```

I'm in the right way?

Comment: Yes you are in the right way

Comment: Beware to the arguments' order ! Your code is wrong...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It shouldn't be much more complex than

```
squares( []     , []     ) .  % squaring the empty list yields the empty list, eh?
squares( [X|Xs] , [Y|Ys] ) :- % for non-empty lists, pull the head of each list, and
  X is Y*Y,                   % - X is Y^2,
  squares(Xs, Ys)             % - then, recurse down on the tails
  .                           % Easy!
```

The trick is to make it bidirectonal, so `squares([1,4,9], X).` yields

```
X = [1,2,3]
```

whilst `squares(X, [1,2,3]).` produces

```
X = [1,4,9]
```

To do that, you'll need to do expand it a bit with a little type-checking:

```
squares( []     , []     ) .
squares( [X|Xs] , [Y|Ys] ) :-
    nonvar(Y),
    X is Y^2,
    squares(Xs,Ys)
    .
squares( [X|Xs] , [Y|Ys] ) :-
    nonvar(X),
    Y is sqrt(X),
    squares(Xs,Ys).
```

You will find, however, that there are some edge cases here, depending on your Prolog implementation, where the difference between integer and floating-point numbers becomes important.